# Does Denver International Airport have Pneumatic Tube Systems?

Tags: aviation

From the Wikipedia page for the [Pneumatic tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube):

> Denver International Airport [DEN] uses many pneumatic tube systems, including a 25 cm diameter system for moving aircraft parts to remote concourses, a 10 cm system for United Airlines ticketing, and a robust system in the parking toll collection system with an outlet at every booth.

The article lacks a citation and their are few credible references on the web. There is a 1994 [Wired](https://www.wired.com/1994/05/tubes-2/) article with this sentence:

> Systems like the one just installed by Denver's Translogic Corp. in that city's new international airport - its 10-foot-diameter tube whisks around airplane parts weighing up to 17 pounds - seem to be pushing the practical limits of pneumatic tube systems.

The lack of references seems suspicious. Yet, a 2017 [Design Standards Manual](https://business.flydenver.com/bizops/documents/denBIM_DSM.pdf) published by DEN mentions pneumatic tubes, as well as a 2017 DEN [press release](https://www.flydenver.com/sites/default/files/downloads/17-027%20Roasting%20Plant.pdf).

**Question**: If these systems actually exist, what are their total lengths (eg. 35 km total) and usage rate (eg. 7000 objects per day)?

Note: The original question was posted (in a shorter form) at [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54390/denver-international-airport-pneumatic-tube-systems) last year by user Nicolas Raoul. No answer has yet been provided.

Comment: There is also this http://www.expo1000.com/parking/press/20000322.htm which talks about using pneumatic tubes to deliver cash to and from parking payment booths. Includes a photo.

Comment: This Scientific American article (on archive.org) also makes passing reference (search "airport"). https://archive.org/stream/757199-pneumatic-tube-article_sa_1995/757199-pneumatic-tube-article_sa_1995_djvu.txt

Comment: This LA Times article http://articles.latimes.com/1994-09-20/business/fi-40928_1_pneumatic-tube-systems says "United Air Lines plans to use a 7,100-foot tube system to shuttle aircraft parts to passenger gates when Denver's huge new airport opens, which is expected next spring." Sounds a bit confused: aircraft parts delivered to passenger gates?

Comment: Have you tried asking Denver Airport?

Comment: @Paul: Can you turn these references into an answer? Pseudo-answers in comments are likely to be deleted.

Comment: They're not as obvious anymore, but pneumatic tube systems used to be quite common, and there was often such a setup running between the business office and the cash registers in US department stores.  Hospitals used them extensively.  Less common anymore, as much activity has been computerized, but still an obvious solution to moving aircraft parts or bundles of money.

Comment: Note that "10-foot-diameter" is likely a mistake on the part of the writer -- 25cm is about ten *inches*.

Comment: Are there any suggestions for improving the question?

Comment: Why exactly would you doubt this? It's convenient and technology that's been around for decades (e.g. at banks).

Comment: We need answers about what exists now, and not hype at the time of construction.  As I recall, at least one DEN automated system (delivering baggage from planes to baggage claim) did not work and had to be scrapped at great expense and replaced by a more conventional system.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I've worked on new hospital additions before, and was surprised to find that they are still installing pneumatic tube systems.

Comment: @JMac - I can recall 40 years ago, both hospital/clinics here (one of them named "Mayo") used conveyor belt systems to move medical records from the filing center to department desks.  This is why medical facilities have been pushing to computerize.

Comment: @Kevin Is Wikipedia the most trustable source? If not, can't we all doubt something in it?

Comment: According to the [Denver Airport Public Relations Office](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54390/denver-international-airport-pneumatic-tube-systems), it no longer user pneumatics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some other references on the Web that appear to be from the time the airport was constructed. They are hard to find because most search hits come up with duplicates of the Wikipedia text.

This [press release](http://expo1000.com/parking/press/20000322.htm) talks about using pneumatic tubes to deliver cash to and from parking payment booths. It includes two photographs and some plans:

[image: Central cash vault]

[image: Long term parking]

[image: Main garage parking]

The numbers in the plans are a bit difficult to read, but it looks like the long term parking has 4*164 + 2 * 1060 = 2776 feet of underground tube, and the main garage parking has 2*2950 = 5900 feet, plus a set of switches to route tubes between the booths and the vault.

I also found [this LA Times article](http://articles.latimes.com/1994-09-20/business/fi-40928_1_pneumatic-tube-systems) from September 1994 which says "*United Air Lines plans to use a 7,100-foot tube system to shuttle aircraft parts to passenger gates when Denver's huge new airport opens, which is expected next spring.*". Although this doesn't mention the diameter it backs up the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Eh, I worked in aviation maintenance for some years. You'd be surprised how often a plane has minor issues that can be taken care of between flights. With the emphasis on fast turnaround times at commercial airports, I could definitely see a use case for a fast delivery method for small parts straight to the gate.

Comment: @IsBegot OK, I'll take out the qualification.

Comment: @IsBegot Once Amazon gets their drone fleet up and running, will they deliver parts in flight?

Comment: @PaulJohnson Thanks for the great research! As you guys (the community) have much more experience than I do, what would you predict would be the "usage rate" of these systems?

Comment: @Acccumulation Unless they're using some seriously impressive drones, I doubt it ;)

Comment: @accc having drones capable of 1200 kph flight is one thing. Having them be able to put a plane part in place is another. Getting an FAA stamp that would let you actually use them is a much tougher beast still.